# android auto refresh listview item

Tags: android, listview

First I setup a ListView adapter

```
this.chapters = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView lvChapters = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mangaChapterList);
lvChapters.setAdapter(new ChapterListAdapter(context, R.id.lvChapters, this.chapters));
```

After that, I popular some data into "this.chapters" in an AsyncTask class. But the listview still empty??

Answer (score 2):

Show the code for your ChapterListAdapter, are you sure you are calling the registered observers?

If ChapterListAdapters is extending an ArrayAdapter, then you should call notifyDataSetChanged.

> public void notifyDataSetChanged ()
>   Since: API Level 1
>
> Notifies the attached View that the underlying data has been changed and it should refresh itself.

Comment: What is it? My adapter class just have constructor and getView method

Comment: It would still be useful to see the code for it. What adapter type does it extend?

Answer (score 1):

Reference your `adapter` through any variable like this

```
ChapterListAdapter adapter = new ChapterListAdapter(context, R.id.lvChapters, this.chapters);
```

and then set adapter.

```
pters.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and then just call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after you add the data to the `this.chapters`.